# Keys on laptop stopped working. Will more keys stop working?

Tags: keyboard

My right arrow key, numpad 4,5,6, and delete button aren't responding to my presses anymore, it was fine before I shut down my laptop last night.
I have been using this laptop for 2 years and 3 months now. Will the non-responsive keys spread out?

Laptop model: ASUS G751JT

Comment: Do you have the same problem with an external keyboard? You should try that to see if it is a software (OS) or hardware issue.

Comment: Yes i had, the external keyboard works, but may i know will the broken keys slowly spread out? As the replacement keyboard for my laptop is so expensive it costs around 80++ usd...

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say if the hardware problem will spread out to other keys. No one can tell you that. In my experience it won't go away by itself.

In my case I just bought a small external keyboard to carry around instead of buying a replacement keyboard.

You may try to take the keyboard out and see if the cable that connects the keyboard is still well connected. Some cleaning of the keys may help. But there is no guarantee it will change anything for the better.

If you plan on using the laptop for several more years, I'd just buy a new keyboard.